# Why does this Facial detection code on python using open cv on raspberry pi outputs a blank screen?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on learning OpenCV, I have tried this example code from the picamera2 library Github and it only outputs a blank window, when it should output the camera footage and some face detection squares. It does not give any error messages when debugging or running the program.

I was not able to find any references to this code or why this could be happening, the camera is working fine.

```
 import cv2

from picamera2 import Picamera2

 #Grab images as numpy arrays and leave everything else to OpenCV.

face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml") cv2.startWindowThread()

picam2 = Picamera2() picam2.configure(picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"format": 'XRGB8888', "size": (640, 480)})) picam2.start()

while True:
    im = picam2.capture_array()

    grey = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(grey, 1.1, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0))

    cv2.imshow("Camera", im)
```

I am running it on a **raspberry pi 4 with bullseye OS**, I have installed **python 3.9.2** on visual studio, and the camera connected is a **raspberry pi HQ camera V1.0 2018**. When using the command libcamera-hello on the terminal it outputs the live footage of the camera just fine.

Comment: where is the waitKey() call? it is required. follow the official docs precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Add `cv2.startWindowThread()` to line 10. I put xml in the **current folder**.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cv2

from picamera2 import Picamera2

# Grab images as numpy arrays and leave everything else to OpenCV.

face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
cv2.startWindowThread()

picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.configure(picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"format": 'XRGB8888', "size": (640, 480)}))
picam2.start()

while True:
    im = picam2.capture_array()

    grey = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(grey, 1.1, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0))

    cv2.imshow("Camera", im)
```